# Playframework: Client is getting 504 HTTP error from Ok.sendFile

Tags: playframework

For the return of one of my POST endpoints I have

```
    Ok.sendFile(
      content = csvFile,
      fileName = (_ => csvFile.fileName),
      onClose = csvFile.cleanup
    )
```

Which sends a csv file to the client. The issue I'm having is that when the csv file is too large (happens rarely for some clients), they receive a 504 Gateway Timeout error.

```
The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.
```

which does not appear when the file is successfully transferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed on gitter : Increase the ELB's timeout values (which default at 60 seconds).

Comment: This will alleviate the problem but isn't a solution we want to go with unfortunately. The long time came from generating the file in the first place so we're going to go with doing the work in the background and providing a link later where they can download it when it's ready.